# Can You Change Site Logo URL?

Tags: mura

Is it possible to change the url for the site logo in the nav bar?

Comment: Are you asking about the Mura logo itself?

Comment: No, we have a logo image uploaded and sits on the left side nav bar when viewing our site.

Comment: A picture of what you are talking about would be helpful. Without some more info it's hard to answer your question. I'm still not sure if you are asking to change some builtin Mura link or your own custom image/link. Either way, it should be possible. Just include some more info so we can help you.